# Reg : publishing paid android apps

Tags: android, publishing

I would like to publish a paid app in the Android market. But since am form India I cannot do so. Is it possible to use one of my friends' account in the US ? 
Also is it possible to map my app to a different account at later time ?

Any info reg the same will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need an Employee identification number from US and also one account number from any US bank.

Comment: ankit,i get that... in future can i map int a differenct account number ?

Comment: I dont think so..because google provides one merchant account to get revenue and this is linked with your bank account no.

Answer (score 0):

Now You can!!
Recently Google has updated the supported countries list for Merchant's account. Now its possible to publish Paid Apps from India.

But as of **24Sept '12** its not working. but hopefully it should in short time.

Read more, [here](http://behindtheapps.tumblr.com/post/32106243610/finally-indian-android-developers-can-publish-paid-apps).

**Update**
25th Sept, '12
Google Removed India from List.No Support as of now. Have to wait again.